# getState function call in action creator always returns empty array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Several calls are being made to action creator "fetchUser" from the several instances of the component "UserHeader". Each call is supposed to add a user to the store. Inside the action creator "fetchUser" a console.log statement is used to show the list of added users using "getState" function. The first call will show user list as empty, but subsequent calls should some users. I don't know why the "getState" function always returns an empty array. Please help with this. The code is hosted at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-meadow-h3ikg)

action creator

```
export const fetchUser = id => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    
  console.log(getState()); // Always empty array

  const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get(`/users/${id}`); // call to external API using Axios

  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_USER', payload: response.data });

};
```

Reducer

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_USER':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

UserHeader

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUser } from '../actions';

class UserHeader extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser(this.props.userId); // call to action creator
  }

  render() {
    const user = this.props.users.find(user => user.id === this.props.userId);

    if (!user) {
      return null;
    }

    return <div className="header">{user.name}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { users: state.users };
};

export default connect( mapStateToProps, { fetchUser } )(UserHeader);
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import App from './components/App';
import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

[Link to image that shows zero Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlv5X.png)

Comment: maybe it's empty because it's not initialized with any value yet? the code looks ok. if you could provide a condesandbox it's will be easier to help you with that!

Comment: @OriEng The code is hosted at https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-meadow-h3ikg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You running in `forEach` and create an API request..the iteration  not waiting until the previous iteration will finish and that's why your store is not updated yet.
If you will console that:

```
export const fetchUser = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  console.log("before:", getState());
  const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get(`/users/${id}`);
  dispatch({ type: "FETCH_USER", payload: response.data });
  console.log("after:", getState());
};
```

you will see:

```
before: (->users don't contain values)
before: (->users don't contain values)
...
after: (->users contain values)
after: (users contain values
..
```

So, basically you need to wait after every iteration.

This is my implementation using [this article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) (also I use `map` and `filter` func instead lodash func , but it's for your decision):

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}

export const fetchPostsAndUsers = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  await dispatch(fetchPosts());

  const postsUsersIds = getState().posts.map((ele) => ele.userId);
  const uniqueVal = postsUsersIds.filter(
    (t, i) => postsUsersIds.indexOf(t) === i
  );

  asyncForEach(uniqueVal, async (val) => {
    await dispatch(fetchUser(val));
  });
};
```

now the values are updated inside `fetchUser` func , you can see the code also in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-shockley-d3rlo?file=/src/actions/index.js:80-589)

Comment: In your image "users: Array[60]" is shown but when I run the same code, I see "users: Array[0]" . This is the link to screenshot . https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlv5X.png

Comment: Thank You very much, that fixed the problem.